# Algorithm similar to the knapsack algorithm (but not really)

Tags: algorithm, set, knapsack-problem

I have a set of numbers of size n (Assume n > 100).

I also have a hard limit x.

What I want is to take a variable number of elements from my set and find a combination of these elements so that when added up the sum is <= x, but as close as possible to x.

Obviously I don't want to do a brute-force approach, is there an efficient algorithm available that solves this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems perfectly suited to the frequently-used pseudo-polynomial knapsack algorithm, which may be discussed in a text you already have or is available at page 41 in [this PDF](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/alcox/lehre/lvws1011/coalg/knapsack.pdf)